# Boost.Spirit : how to parse length preceeding byte array?

Tags: c++, boost, binary, hex, boost-spirit

I need to parse the following byte array "080100000113fc208dff01".

Here :

- 1-st byte "08" - ID
- 2-nd byte "01" - length of 8-bytes array
- 3-10 bytes - element of 8-byte array
- 11-th byte "01" - length of 8-bytes array (should be the same as 2-nd byte)

I was trying to use qi::repeat(), followed the manual and implemented the following parser [Link To Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94f528c9fde9e575)

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <vector>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

typedef unsigned int BYTE;
typedef unsigned long long ULONGLONG;

struct AVLData
{
    ULONGLONG m_timestamp;
    BYTE m_priority;
};

struct AVLDataArray
{
    BYTE m_codecID;
    BYTE m_numOfData;
    std::vector<AVLData> m_data;
    BYTE m_numOfData_last;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AVLDataArray, m_codecID, m_numOfData, m_data,     m_numOfData_last)

template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper = qi::ascii::blank_type>
    struct Grammar: qi::grammar <Iterator, AVLDataArray(), Skipper>
    {
        Grammar() : Grammar::base_type(avl_array)
        {
            qi::uint_parser<BYTE, 16, 2, 2> uint_byte_p;
            qi::uint_parser<unsigned long long, 16, 16, 16> uint_8_byte_p;

            avl_array = uint_byte_p > uint_byte_p[qi::_a = qi::_1] >    qi::repeat(qi::_a)[uint_8_byte_p > uint_byte_p] > uint_byte_p;

            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((avl_array));
        }

    private:
        qi::rule<Iterator, AVLDataArray(), Skipper, qi::locals<BYTE>> avl_array;
};

int main() {
    std::string const input = "080100000113fc208dff01";

    auto f(begin(input)), l(end(input));
    Grammar<std::string::const_iterator> g;

    AVLDataArray array;
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f,l,g,qi::blank,array);

    if (ok && f == l) 
    {
        std::cout << "Parse succeeded\n";
    } else
    {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
         std::cout << "->stopped at [" + std::string(f, l) + "]";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But for now, I'm faced 2 problems :

1) I'm not sure I understand how to use locals (local with the same name) in 2 qi::rules. 
For example, is such code valid ? :

```
data = qi::repeat(qi::_a)[uint_8_byte_p > uint_byte_p];
vl_array = uint_byte_p > uint_byte_p[qi::_a = qi::_1] > data > uint_byte_p;
```

2) My example is not compiling with error

```
grammar.hpp:75:13: error: static assertion failed: incompatible_start_rule...
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

-Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first:

> grammar.hpp:75:13: error: static assertion failed: incompatible_start_rule...

means (surprise) that you use an incompatible start rule. The offender is the `locals<>` argument that is missing on the grammar baseclass declaration. Instead of adding that implementation detail to the public interface, consider using a wrapping start rule that invokes the real parser  entry point that *does* have the `locals<>` argument.

---

Further more:

- what is the `m_priority` thing about? Your question doesn't address it, and neither does the sample input (so it shouldn't parse, as there's just the 8byte element, and no priority to follow).
- did you forget to adapt `AVLData`?
- ignoring that, rules with semantic actions don't auto-propagate their attributes. This is fine because you probably don't need those redundant counts in your AST node (`m_numOfData` and `m_numOfData_last`)

  You can force automatic propagation by using `operator%=` instead of `operator=` to assign the rule definition.
- You can use `omit` to omit attributes from the synthesized attribute
- You probably want to validate the opening/closing bytes e.g.:

  ```
  uint_byte_p(0x08)
  ```

  <strike>To check whether the closing byte matches the second say:</strike>

  ```
  qi::omit[uint_byte_p [ qi::_pass = (qi::_a == qi::_1) ] ]
  ```

  > *Thanks for @jv_ making be double-check again, you can indeed just say `omit(uint_byte_p(_a))` there too.*
- If your grammar specifies `ascii::blank_type` you can't pass `qi::blank` for it. It needs to match. Once again: consider hiding the skipper using a start rule, instead of exposing the implementation detail.
- Also, in this particular example I'd be surprised if you really want to accept blanks everywhere in the input string. Note too that `int_parser` is implicitly *lexeme* (meaning the array element or bytes cannot contain blanks even in this configuration). You should check whether this all matches your requirements.
- Your use of expectation points practically rules out the possibility of the parse failing without an exception (unless the first byte cannot be parsed, since the first `uint_byte_p` isn't preceded by an expectation point like `qi::eps > uint_byte_p`). Consider using `>>` to get normal sequence semantics.

Fixing these issues results in working code:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01b3f4b41d1e4170)</kbd>**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

typedef unsigned int BYTE; // what large bytes you have, grandma!?

struct AVLData {
    uint64_t m_timestamp;
    BYTE m_priority;
};

struct AVLDataArray {
    BYTE m_codecID;
    std::vector<AVLData> m_data;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AVLData, m_timestamp, m_priority) // you need to adapt all your types
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AVLDataArray, m_codecID, m_data)

template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper = ascii::blank_type>
    struct Grammar: qi::grammar <Iterator, AVLDataArray(), Skipper>
    {
        Grammar() : Grammar::base_type(start)
        {
            qi::uint_parser<BYTE, 16, 2, 2> uint_byte_p;
            qi::uint_parser<uint64_t, 16, 16, 16> uint_8_byte_p;

            avl_array %= uint_byte_p(0x08)
                      >> qi::omit[uint_byte_p[qi::_a = qi::_1]] 
                      >> qi::repeat(qi::_a)[uint_8_byte_p >> uint_byte_p]
                      >> qi::omit[uint_byte_p [ qi::_pass = (qi::_a == qi::_1) ] ]
                      ;

            start      = avl_array;

            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((avl_array)(start));
        }

    private:
        qi::rule<Iterator, AVLDataArray(), Skipper> start;
        qi::rule<Iterator, AVLDataArray(), Skipper, qi::locals<BYTE>> avl_array;
};

int main() {
    std::string const input = "080100000113fc208dff" /*priority:*/ "2a" /*end prioirity*/ "01";

    auto f(begin(input)), l(end(input));
    Grammar<std::string::const_iterator> g;

    AVLDataArray array;
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f,l,g,ascii::blank,array);

    if (ok && f == l) 
    {
        std::cout << "Parse succeeded\n";
        std::cout << "Codec: " << array.m_codecID << "\n";
        for(auto& element : array.m_data)
            std::cout << "element: 0x" << std::hex << element.m_timestamp << " prio " << std::dec << element.m_priority << "\n";
    } else
    {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
        std::cout << "->stopped at [" + std::string(f, l) + "]";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
Parse succeeded
Codec: 8
element: 0x113fc208dff prio 42
```

And with debug info enabled:

```
<start>
  <try>080100000113fc208dff</try>
  <avl_array>
    <try>080100000113fc208dff</try>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[[8, [[1185345998335, 42]]]]</attributes><locals>(1)</locals>
  </avl_array>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[8, [[1185345998335, 42]]]]</attributes>
</start>
```

### BONUS:

> Can I use the local across rules?

No. You need to inherit attributes:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/579bc328fd86f3ce)</kbd>**

```
    data       = qi::repeat(qi::_r1)[uint_8_byte_p >> uint_byte_p]
              ;
    avl_array %= uint_byte_p(0x08)
              >> qi::omit[uint_byte_p[qi::_a = qi::_1]] 
              >> data(qi::_a)
              >> qi::omit[uint_byte_p [ qi::_pass = (qi::_a == qi::_1) ] ]
              ;
```

With the rules as:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<AVLData>(BYTE), Skipper> data;
qi::rule<Iterator, AVLDataArray(),             Skipper, qi::locals<BYTE>> avl_array;
```

Comment: Nice answer, I think `uint_byte_p [ qi::_pass == (qi::_a == qi::_1) ]` could also be written as `uint_byte_p(qi::_a)`.

Comment: @jv_ my tests told me otherwise. (The lack of this feature makes a tiny bit of sense from a performance standpoint I guess)

Comment: If it's not too much bother, could you show those tests? I think [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c0a5c7728b5c34e) does what it should (and apparently (and confusingly since it should definitely work) [yours does not](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ea8dfcbc3776f6c)). The use of a lazy argument that evaluates to an unsigned integer is [in the docs](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/numeric/uint.html#spirit.qi.reference.numeric.uint.model_of)

Comment: I must have hit a bug or messed up somewhere. Let me check later when I have time

Comment: Oops. `_pass ==` should be assignment (`_pass =`) @jv_ will edit when I'm back home

Comment: Yep, we are both blind :p.

Comment: @sehe, great thanks and sorry for stupid error with "BYTE"! For this question I googled much to understand how to deal with inherited attributes and/or local variables but failed to find clear answer. I'm still not sure I understsand how inherited attributes are passed between rules, why _r1 but not _r2 ? PS: I'm studying spirit by your answers on stackoverflow :)

Comment: If you had more inherited attributes, they would become `_r2`, `_r3`... in the context of the "called" rule. See http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/attribute_handling/the-magical-power-of-attributes-in-spirit-directives-and-non-terminals/ for a good intro.

Comment: @jv_ It seems I misread the results of my testing (maybe before I added the "priority" byte to the input). I amended the text a little to reflect that more logical code.

Comment: I have updated test-case to use binary parser : [Live On  Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4723f4d4ed06acc1). Unfortunately fails to compile online but works with VS2015 compiler.

Comment: @drus Blame stupid MSVC compiler extensions: `auto f(input.cbegin()), l(input.cend());` (or just use `s/const_iterator/iterator` or don't use `auto`): [here's your change](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58fe8097fcbfa6b4) :) Good to see you dropped the skipper. I've dropped your `_pass` thing again

Comment: @sehe, ah, I see, thanks :) 1 question : is there a way with "byte_" parser to pass expected value ? The same way, you suggested with uint_byte_p() like avl_array %= uint_byte_p(0x08) >>... . I tried something like qi::byte[qi::_pass =(qi::_1 == 0x08)] but it changes auto rule and adopting doesn't work.

Comment: Played a bit more with binary parsers. I hardly understand why qi::qword (as well as other binary parsers) fails to parse "\x00". See live example : [live Coliru example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ca2836b1fdf9edc).

Comment: @drus Nothing to do with Spirit. Use `std::string("\x00\x01\x01\x13\xfc\x20\x8d\xff", 8)` as per http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string Thank legacy C compatibility

Comment: @sehe, again thanks for your patience and answer! I implemented everything as I wanted.